# How to insert inline Python code that evaluates to value in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have the following line in `markdown` cell in a jupyter notebook

```
The value of 2+2 is `{2+2}`.
```

Expected result is

```
The value of 2+2 is 4.
```

But it is not working. Please fix this code.

Comment: Default Jupyter doesn't have that ability, and so the code isn't necessarily the the problem. You are seeking [Python Markdown extension](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/python-markdown/readme.html?highlight=markdown#python-markdown) or Jupyter Lab with the Myst tool extension (see [here](https://twitter.com/rowancockett/status/1638423275968811008) for pointing it out posted demonstration & [here for tool repo](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyterlab-myst)). For JupyterLab-Myst Tools you can try it right in your browser without logging in ...

Comment: <continued>  by going [here](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyterlab-myst#jupyterlab-myst-extension) and clicking on '`launch binder`'. Myst markdown is also related to [the Jupyter Book project](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/intro.html).

Comment: More background can be found starting [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/inline-variable-insertion-in-markdown/10525?u=fomightez). The thread eventually discusses functionality that evolved to being used in jupyterlab-myst.